# Find and Round Object in a Generic List

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I am carrying out a university project in which they make us use generic nodes and generic lists. I have a class called Process which has a set of activities.
I need to be able to relate this Process to my list of activities, the user enters the ID of the Process and internally, I must look for the ID in the list of processes (Generic) and return the entire Process object.

```
public class NodoGenerico<T> {
    private ArrayList<NodoGenerico<T>> enlaces;
    // Variable en la cual se va a guardar el valor.
    private T dato;
    // Variable para enlazar los nodos.
    private NodoGenerico<T> siguiente;
    private NodoGenerico<T> anterior;

    public NodoGenerico(T dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public T getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(T valor) {
        this.dato = valor;
    }

    public NodoGenerico<T> getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(NodoGenerico<T> siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }

    public NodoGenerico<T> getAnterior() {
        return anterior;
    }

    public void setAnterior(NodoGenerico<T> anterior) {
        this.anterior = anterior;
    }

    public void conectar(NodoGenerico<T> nodo, int indice) {
        // Se valida el posicionamiento del vector.

        if (indice < enlaces.size()) {
            enlaces.set(indice, nodo);
        } else {
            int n = indice - enlaces.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                enlaces.add(null);
            }
            enlaces.add(nodo);
        }
    }
```

This is the class NodeGenerico
I appreciate your collaboration since I have consulted and I have not been able to find the solution.

Comment: You can't - you've got a Node that can hold anything, therefore, it could hold apples. What is the ID of an apple? There isn't one - thus, what you want is impossible. Now, stick a bound on that T and maybe we can get somewhere. For example, `NodeGenerico<T extends SomeParentTypeThatHasThatID>`.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your answer!